# Debugging Blackjack program? (Java)

Tags: java, debugging, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to write a Blackjack program where the user bets against a CPU dealer.
The problem I am having is that I have written classes for card, deck, and dealer, but when I try to initialize a new dealer and a new deck I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Blackjack.Deck.<init>(Deck.java:12)
at Blackjack.Blackjack.main(Blackjack.java:10)
```

Here is my class for **card**:

```
 class Card {
      private int rank;
      private int suit;
      private int value;
      private static String[] ranks = {"Joker","Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
      private static String[] suits = {"Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades"};

      Card(int suit, int values)
      {
           this.rank=values;
           this.suit=suit;
           if(rank>10)
           {
                value=10;
           }
           else
                value=rank;
      }
      public String toString()
      {
      return ranks[rank]+" of "+suits[suit];
      }
      public int getRank()
      {
      return rank;
      }
      public int getSuit()
      {
           return suit;
      }
      public int getValue()
      {
           return value;
      }
      public void setValue(int set)
      {
           value = set;
      }
 }
```

my class for **deck**:

```
package Blackjack;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

 class Deck {
      private ArrayList<Card> deck;
      Deck()
      {
           for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
           {
                for(int j=1; j<=13; j++)
                {
                     deck.add(new Card(i,j));
                }
           }
      }
      public void shuffle()
      {
           Random random = new Random();
           Card temp;
           for(int i=0; i<200; i++)
           {
                int index1 = random.nextInt(deck.size()-1);
                int index2 = random.nextInt(deck.size()-1);
                temp = deck.get(index2);
                deck.set(index2, deck.get(index1));
                deck.set(index1, temp);
           }
      }
      public Card drawCard()
      {
           return deck.remove(0);
      }
 }
```

my class for **dealer**:

```
package Blackjack;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
class Dealer {
ArrayList<Card> hand;
private int handvalue=0;
private Card[] aHand;
Dealer(Deck deck)
{
    hand = new ArrayList<>();
    aHand = new Card[]{};
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        hand.add(deck.drawCard());
    }
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    for(int i=0; i<aHand.length; i++)
    {
        handvalue += aHand[i].getValue();
        if(aHand[i].getValue()==1 && handvalue<12)
        {
            handvalue=handvalue+10;
        }
    }
}
public String showFirstCard()
{
    Card[] firstCard = new Card[]{};
    firstCard = hand.toArray(firstCard);
    return firstCard[0].toString();
}
public void Hit(Deck deck)
{
    hand.add(deck.drawCard());
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    handvalue = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<aHand.length; i++)
    {
        handvalue += aHand[i].getValue();
        if(aHand[i].getValue()==1 && handvalue<12)
        {
            handvalue=handvalue+10;
        }
    }
}
public boolean wantsToHit()
{
    if(handvalue<17)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean hasBlackJack()
{
    if(hand.size()==2 && handvalue==21)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public String showHand()
{
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    String hands="";
    for(int i=0; i<aHand.length-1; i++)
    {
        hands = aHand[i].toString()+", ";
    }
    hands = hands + aHand[aHand.length-1].toString();
    return hands;
}
public int getHandValue()
{
    return handvalue;
}
```

}

And my main method:

```
 public class Blackjack {
 private static int cash;
 public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println("Hi! What is your name?");
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      String name = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Hello, "+name+" lets plays some BlackJack!");
      Deck deck = new Deck();
      deck.shuffle();
      Dealer dealer = new Dealer(deck);
      System.out.println(dealer.showHand());
      System.out.println(dealer.getHandValue());
      }
 }
```

Any help would be VERY much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Deck` the attribute `deck` is never initialized and thus `null`. Since `deck` is `null` this line: `deck.add(new Card(i,j));` will throw a `NullPointerException`. Simply create `deck` before the for-loops to solve this problem

```
Deck()
{
    deck = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=13; j++)
        {
            deck.add(new Card(i,j));
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jared you didn't post the complete code of `Dealer`, but i guess you don't initialize any variables directly, so most likely yes

Comment: can I ask you another question?

Comment: @Jared sure, that's the purpose of SO ^^

Comment: for my dealer class, I can't get his hand to update when i call the hit method. His hand value updates, but not his hand array list. I'll edit the post to include the rest of the dealer class. Thank you SO much for helping me. This is my first multi class program >.<

Comment: so what happens is when i do the system.out.println it has the correct hand value but it doesn't add the third card to the hand.

Comment: @Jared you never call `Hit` in the provided code. Have you forgotten to update that part? Or is that the actual mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Deck()`, You need to add this:

```
deck = new ArrayList<Card>(); // Same for hand in Dealer class
```

And here,

```
aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
for(int i=0; i<aHand.length; i++)
{
    handvalue += aHand[i].getValue();
    if(aHand[i].getValue()==1 && handvalue<12)
    {
        handvalue=handvalue+10;
    }
}
```

can be changed to

```
for(Card c : hand) {
    handvalue += c.getValue();
    // rest of code
    // And I think inside your if,
    // It should be handvalue += 9? You already added the value '1' before.
    // If I remember how to play blackjack correctly, counting Ace as 10?
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to do this for all your ArrayList (assuming hand is also `ArrayList<Card>`)